# React JS Error, Cannot read property 'value' of null when processing login form

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm attempting to build a login form using react create, which consumes the user name and password values from the following json API: https://api.myjson.com/bins/fyufr

The code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './Login.css';

class Login extends Component { 

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { 
            data: [], 
            userName: "",
            password: "",
            token: "",
        };
    } //end constructor

         change = (e) => {
            this.setState({
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            });
        }; //end change

        onSubmit = (e) =>{
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(this.state);
            this.setState({
                userName: "",
                password: "",
                token: "",
            });

            var userName = document.getElementById('userName').value
            var password = document.getElementById('password').value

            for(var i=0; i < this.state.data.length; i++) {
                if(userName == this.state.data[i].userName && password == this.state.data[i].password){
                    console.log(userName + "is logged in")
                }
            }
                    console.log("incorrect username or password")

        };

     componentWillMount() {
        fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/fyufr', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            /*body: JSON.stringify({
                username: '{userName}',
                password: '{password}'
            })*/
        }) /*end fetch */
        .then(results => results.json()) 
        .then(data => this.setState({ data: data })   
    )

} //end life cycle

    render() {
    console.log(this.state.data);
        return (
            <form>
                <input 
                name="userName"
                placeholder="User Name"
                value={this.state.userName}
                onChange={e => this.change(e) } 
                 />  <br />

                 <input 
                name="password"
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                value={this.state.password}
                onChange={e => this.change(e) } 
                 />  <br />

                  <input 
                name="token"
                placeholder="Token"
                value={this.state.token}
                onChange={e => this.change(e) }  
                 />  <br />

               <button onClick={e => this.onSubmit(e)}>Submit</button>  
            </form>
        );
      }
}

export default Login;
```

My code errors out on the following line: 
var userName = document.getElementById('userName').value

...the values of this.state.data outputs to the console the values in the json file, but I get the error mentioned above when the submit button is clicked.  My goal is to have the login form direct the user to a landing page upon entering a matching username and password, but first, I'm trying to resolve the error am encountering. I'm new to React JS, could I please get some guidance as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix. You are missing `id` on your form inputs. You are trying to get `document.getElementById('userName').value` which returns `null` because it dont exist.

Here's working example of your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-m7iwpt

Comment: Thank You, I cannot believed I missed that. I greatly appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set an I'd on your input...